# Serde won't derive for a generic struct

Tags: rust, compiler-errors, traits, serde

So I am trying to use `serde` and `postcard` to serialize and deserialize a certain generic structure (`HashStore<T: ImgHashOutput>`). It would be *nice* if I could serialize and deserialize for all `ImgHashOutput`, but I really just need it to work for `u128`. Here are the structures and traits involved.

```rust
pub trait ImgHashOutput:
    Default + AddAssign + ShlAssign<u8> + From<u8> + Copy + IntegerStuff + Serialize + DeserializeOwned {}

impl<T> ImgHashOutput for T where
    T: Default + AddAssign + ShlAssign<u8> + From<u8> + Copy + IntegerStuff + Serialize + DeserializeOwned {}

// store a vec of perceptual image hashes that correspond to a specific character
#[derive(Debug, Serialize, Deserialize)]
pub struct StoreValue<T: ImgHashOutput> {
    pub value: char,
    pub hashes: Vec<T>,
}

// collection of StoreValue for all the characters that can be recognized
#[derive(Debug, Serialize, Deserialize)]
pub struct HashStore<T: ImgHashOutput> {
    pub arr: Vec<StoreValue<T>>
}

pub trait SerdeStoreValue:
    Serialize + DeserializeOwned
{}

impl<T> SerdeStoreValue for T where
    T: Serialize + DeserializeOwned
{}
```

The code bellow works perfectly (as far as I can tell). I included it for context.

```rust
pub trait IntegerStuff {
    const BITS: u32;
    fn hamming_dist<T: ImgHashOutput>(a: Self, b: Self) -> u32;
}

macro_rules! impl_integer_stuff {
    ($type:ty) => {
        impl IntegerStuff for $type {
            const BITS: u32 = (<$type>::BITS) as u32;
        
            #[inline(always)]
            fn hamming_dist<T: ImgHashOutput>(a: Self, b: Self) -> u32 {
                (a ^ b).count_ones() as u32
            }
        }
    };
}

impl_integer_stuff!(i8);
impl_integer_stuff!(u8);
impl_integer_stuff!(i16);
impl_integer_stuff!(u16);
impl_integer_stuff!(i32);
impl_integer_stuff!(u32);
impl_integer_stuff!(i64);
impl_integer_stuff!(u64);
impl_integer_stuff!(i128);
impl_integer_stuff!(u128);
impl_integer_stuff!(isize);
impl_integer_stuff!(usize);
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed to omit the `ImgHashOutput` bound on `StoreValue`.

[source](https://discord.com/channels/273534239310479360/1100636557699993650/1100644553142304821): wowie#4254 on discord